# Is there a way to prevent strings from behaving like multi-Dimensional Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

My problem is I have some code to check whether an array is multidimensional or not.

```
if( typeof( ary[ 0 ][ 0 ] ) != 'undefined' )
{
    alert( "this array is 2 dimensional" );
}
else
{   
    alert( "this array is not 2 dimensional" )
}
```

This works for arrays that consist only of numbers. But when I have arrays full of strings like

```
var ary = [ "one", "two", "three" ];
```

JavaScript seems to make this array inherently multidimensional. I can access each letter by going:

```
alert( ary[ 0 ][ 0 ] );//This returns the letter "o" from "one"
```

The problem is that the `typeof` of `ary[ 0 ][ 0 ]` is not undefined, but it is a string. So How can I make this return undefined if my array isn't truly 2 dimensional? Yes I'm newbie and thx.

Comment: Well `typeof ary[0]` will be `string` not `object`, for one thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent strings from behaving like multi-Dimensional Arrays?

You can't change the behavior of strings, no, but that test is open to other problems as well. For instance, it'll say this is a two-dimensional array:

```
var obj = {0: {0: "foo"}}; // Yes, that's valid syntax. Rare, but valid.
```

Instead, consider [`Array.isArray`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3.2):

```
if (Array.isArray(ary) && Array.isArray(ary[0]))
{
    alert( "this array is 2 dimensional" );
}
else
{   
    alert( "this array is not 2 dimensional" )
}
```

`Array.isArray` was added in ES5, but can be easily shimmed for really old engines:

```
if (!Array.isArray) {
    (function() {
        var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
        Array.isArray = function(arg) {
            return toString.call(arg) === "[object Array]";
        };
    })();
}
```

---

Side note: JavaScript doesn't *have* multi-dimensional arrays. It has arrays, which can contain other arrays. Just because there's an array at index `0` doesn't mean that there's an array at index `1`.

Comment: Perfect. for newbies like me this explanation was easy to follow. Especially sense you show what changes and stays the same from my original code.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check if an object is a multidimensional array instead:

```
if (Array.isArray(ary) && Array.isArray(ary[0])) { ... }
```

Note that `Array.isArray` is an ES5 addition, but if you need to support older browsers, jQuery has [`$.isArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/) and lodash/underscore.js has [`_.isArray`](https://lodash.com/docs#isArray). If you're not using either of those, MDN has the following polyfill:

```
if (!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function(arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use libraries like lodash.

Check this function https://lodash.com/docs#isArray

E.g.

```
if (_.isArray(ary) && _.isArray(ary[0]))
{
  alert( "this array is 2 dimensional" );
}
else
{   
  alert( "this array is not 2 dimensional" )
}
```